# Increase space between group of bars Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have the following picture

```
    figure
    y = [2 2 3 2 5 6 2 8 9];
    h=bar(y)
    name_x = {'0','1','2','4','5','6','8','9','10'}
    set(gca,'Xtick',1:9,'XTickLabel',name_x,'XTickLabelRotation',45)
```

I would like to increase the space between the first group of bars named 0 1 2 and the second group of bars named 4 5 6. Next also between the second and the third named 8 9 10.

I can't recreate the figure... Is it possible to modify it after that it has been created (I have the handle)?

Comment: I think you need to customize your plot using `figure` and `patch`.

Answer (score 2):

```
figure
y = [2 2 3 NaN 2 5 6 NaN 2 8 9];
bar(y)
name_x = {'0','1','2','','4','5','6','','8','9','10'}
set(gca,'Xtick',1:11,'XTickLabel',name_x,'XTickLabelRotation',45)
```

Incidentally, `'XTickLabelRotation',45` throws an error for me on Matlab 2015a

Also if you want to eliminate the tick marks in the gap then instead of `1:11` you should use `[1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11]`.

Comment: Hi Dan. I can't recreate the figure. I need to modify it once already created

Comment: @gabboshow might be easiest if you extract the data from the figure. So... your code is not calling `bar(y)`?

Comment: No, I have just the picture...the code that I posted was  an example to  have a picture that looked like mine...

Comment: please edit your question then to be more explicit. What format is the picture in? How many times will you need to do this? Are you sure that this isn't a job for photoshop?